# GIT Push - [remote rejected] to ssh key

Tags: git

I have a problem on git push because of file on objects diretory of /.git
The terminal displays the following message:

```
Enumerating objects: 38, done.
Counting objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 14.40 KiB | 921.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 22 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: unable to write file ./objects/ec/3a800eea2d9c0fd32db2d5943c2c059ab79b10: Permission denied
To ssh://mysshAdress.git
 ! [remote rejected]   feat/ficha-28-09-wtdb -> feat/ficha-28-09-wtdb (unable to migrate objects to permanent storage)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://mysshAdress.git'
```

I've never seen this before and it's causing a big problem.

Has anyone ever experienced this? tks

Comment: Looks like a problem on your git hosting solution. Contact them.

Comment: I already talked with them. The permissions are okay. I don't  know how I can solve this

Comment: to me the error looks like they ran out o storage.

Comment: The permissions *aren't* OK, hence the "unable to migrate" error. But it must be handled on their end *or* by you logging in to their system as a different user (the latter seems unlikely, but is a possibility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
error: unable to write file
```

That error message is *not* prefixed with `remote:`, which means the disk spaceo or permission issue is on your side, on your local computer.

Depending on your OS, check the permissions/ACL associated with your `.git./objects/` folder, and see if you need to chmod/modify said ACLs.

Make sure your local repository is not in a synchronized folder (DropBox, OneDrive, ...)